# How to obtain a nested HTML list from object's array recordset?

Tags: php, list, recursion, nested

I have this array of objects returned by a SQL query where top_id is my parent ID field:

```
Array (
[0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [top_id] => 0 [name] => Cat 1 )
[1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [top_id] => 0 [name] => Cat 2 ) 
[2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 3 [top_id] => 0 [name] => Cat 3 ) 
[3] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 4 [top_id] => 2 [name] => Subcat 1 ) 
[4] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 5 [top_id] => 2 [name] => Subcat 2 ) 
[5] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 6 [top_id] => 3 [name] => Subcat 3 ) 
[6] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 7 [top_id] => 5 [name] => Subcat 4 )
)
```

Now I need to obtain a nested  list like this using PHP:

```
<ul>
  <li>Cat 1</li>
  <li>Cat 2
    <ul>
      <li>Subcat 1</li>
      <li>Subcat 2
        <ul>
          <il>Subcat 3
            <ul>
              <li>Subcat 4</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Cat 3</li>
</ul>
```

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Does "top_id" indicate which category a sub-category belongs to?

Answer (score 10):

First of all map the objects onto a new hash (array) in which the index is the `id`:

```
// map the array onto hash
$hash = array();
foreach($array as $object)
{
    $hash[$object->id] = array('object' => $object);
}
```

Then transpose this flat hash into a tree-like structure, see this [answer for another code example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7673044/367456#7673415), it's merely the same here:

```
// build tree from hash
$tree = array();
foreach($hash as $id => &$node)
{
    if ($parent = $node['object']->top_id)
        $hash[$parent]['children'][] =& $node;
    else
        $tree[] =& $node;
}
unset($node, $hash);
```

Finally you can output this tree-like structure as HTML. This can be done with either a stack or recursive. This is one variant with recursion:

```
// render tree
function render_tree($tree)
{
    echo '<ul>', "\n";
    foreach($tree as $node)
    {
        render_node($node);
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

// render tree node
function render_node($node, $level = 0)
{
    $inset = str_repeat('    ', $level) . '  ';
    echo $inset, '<li>', $node['object']->name;
    if (isset($node['children']))
    {
        echo "\n", $inset, '  <ul>', "\n";
        foreach($node['children'] as $node)
        {
            render_node($node, $level+1);
        }
        echo $inset, '  </ul>', "\n", $inset;
    }
    echo '</li>', "\n";
}

// output
render_tree($tree);
```

Output:

```
<ul>
  <li>Cat 1</li>
  <li>Cat 2
    <ul>
      <li>Subcat 1</li>
      <li>Subcat 2
        <ul>
          <li>Subcat 4</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Cat 3
    <ul>
      <li>Subcat 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[Full code Example + HTML Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/I8p7aI).