# Making a HTML category list (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, html, categories

I have a table called Category, following this pattern:

id | name | parent_id

So, if category x is child of y, then x's parent_id is y's id.

I also have a function that returns an array with all the columns of each row.

Its return format is this:

returned_array[category_id1] = array([category_name], [category_parent_id]
returned_array[category_id2] = array([category_name], [category_parent_id]

etc... that takes care of fetching all categories into one array.

Now I want to code a function that will return

```
<li>Category 1
    <li>Child 1</li>
    <li>Child 2
     <li>Child x</li>
    </li>
</li>
<li>Category 2
    <li>Child 1</li>
    // etc
</li>
```

I'm breaking my head on this but I just cant figure out a way to do this...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Category Hierarchy (PHP/MySQL)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452472/category-hierarchy-php-mysql)

Comment: Why not grab the parents, loop through them, and while looping through, query for children using the parent's id

Comment: Not directly relevant to the question, but your markup is incorrect, you cannot directly nest an `<li>` inside another `<li>`. You have to put another list (`<ul>` or `<ol>`) inside the parent `<li>` and put your child `<li>` elements in there.

Answer (score 0):

try this. i didnt test it if there are errors but the idea is here

```
<?php

$aCats = array(
    1 = array(
        'name'=>'Category 1',
        'childs'=> array(
            2 = array(
                'name'=>'Category 1 - A',
                'childs'=> array();
            );  
        );
    );
);

function printParentChild($aCats)
{
    $sHtml = '';

    foreach($aCats as $aCat)
    {
        if(array_key_exists('childs', $aCat) && is_array($aCat['childs']) )
            $sHtml .= printParentChild($aCat['childs']);

        $sHtml .= '<li>'.$aCat.'</li>';
    }
    return '<ul>'.$sHtml.'</ul>';
}

echo $aCats;
```

Answer (score -1):

In this scenarios you need 2 arrays to process it easily ans without complex, first array should have all your categories e.g)

```
$catArr[categoryId] =  'categoryName';
```

your second array should have only parent Id as key and child array as value e.g)

```
$subCatArr[parentId] = Array([0]=>firstChildId, [1]=> secondChildId ..etc)
$subCatArr[parentId] = Array([0]=>firstChildId, [1]=> secondChildId ..etc)
```

Now you can loop through your $subCatArr array and have one more loop to have childs and get name of categories from $catArr array.

**you can do this method which is much used and much easy also,**

first run query to fetch categoryname and  distinct parent Id and loop through it and inside the loop run another query to fetch all records which is having parent Id as current loop id.