# Category and subcategory through a single query

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a table with fields `id,pid,name`.I want to fetch the data in the following format through a single query.

```
id- parent category name- name
```

Name would be either category or subcategory and parent category name would be none if its parent else will be parent category name.

Comment: this is the unlimited multilevel architecture, parent can be the id of the parent cat if it's root it will be 0

Comment: take a look on this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452472/category-hierarchy-php-mysql) // also see side related links

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select t.id,
        tp.name as parent_category,
        t.name as category
from table t
full join table tp on tp.id = t.pid
```

Comment: Shouldn't you give `tp.name`, and `t.name` specific identifiers so you can return the result as an associative array? something like: `tp.name as 'parent_name'` and `t.name as 'child_name'`

Comment: Yes `as` is used to name columns in a select statement. It is meant for instances such as this when you are returning two columns with the same name. When wouldn't be able to use the result as a associative array since 'name' will be set twice.

Comment: @BrookJulias, sorry - i've deleted that comment as it seems i've read yours wrong. you are right, dunno why i said such a thing =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query:

```
SELECT c.name,pc.name FROM category c left join category pc on c.pid = pc.id;
```