# How to sort the result by displaying parent id first then all the children id underneath it

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have set of results like this

```
ID >> Parent
1  >> 0
2  >> 0
3  >> 0
4  >> 1
5  >> 1
6  >> 2
7  >> 1
8  >> 0 
9  >> 3
10 >> 0
```

I want to sort the record in a way where I display the records by having parent and underneath it all of it children. So the results will look like this

```
1  >> 0
4  >> 1
5  >> 1
7  >> 1
2  >> 0
6  >> 2
3  >> 0
9  >> 3
8  >> 0 
10 >> 0
```

**How can sort the records in this order using MySQL?**

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL SELECT Tree Parent IDs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688376/mysql-select-tree-parent-ids).

Comment: I have tried Sort By id, parent   that did not work. Also have tried ORDER BY COALESCE(parent, id), parent, id. this did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support recursive queries. But if a parent can't have a parent (like in your sample data) you could use something like this:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     mytable
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Parent=0 THEN ID ELSE Parent END, ID
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d389a/2).

Comment: This worked indeed.  any known reason why MySQL does not support recursive queries? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe...

```
SELECT id,COALESCE(parent,id) p FROM my_table ORDER BY p,id;
```